# Paramiko возвращает EOF при выполнении команды

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Знатоки, подскажите что не так.

Пытаюсь сделать простой скрипт, который коннектится по ssh до acme sbc и получает uptime. Почему-то на шаге *stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)* получаю  *DEBUG:paramiko.transport:**EOF** in transport thread* ну и дальше всё фейлится.

```
import paramiko

host = '192.168.1.2'
user = 'user'
secret = 'password'
port = 22
paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)

def runCmd(hostname, username, password, cmd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname, username=username, password=password)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    stdout.readlines()
    ssh.close()

runCmd(host, user, secret, 'show uptime')
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Посмотрите на [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), это обертка над paramiko + всякие плюшки + [fabtools](https://fabtools.readthedocs.org/en/0.19.0/) Легок в использовании и почти никаких заморочек )

Comment: но этот *raise EOFError()* выдаёт мне как раз paramiko, а значит fabric не подойдёт, раз он оболочка.
Ещё я из под Win + Py3, т.е. вроде как совсем fabric не подходит.
Ещё пробовал spur, но т.к. это тот же paramiko только проще, то он выдаёт тоже исключение.

Comment: А что будет если вы со своей машины ручками выполните эту команду через ssh? Т.е. выполнить команды как показано [здесь](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-running-commands-on-a-remote-host.html)

Comment: А вы точно на этом шаге получаете сообщение? У меня это сообщение на `close` вроде появляется. Т.е. все отрабатывает. Вы же не выводите ничего, сделайте `print(stdout.readlines())` и скорее всего увидите, что все у вас в норме

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример кода, который выполняет `uptime` команду через `ssh`, используя `paramiko`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import paramiko # $ pip install paramiko

host = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "localhost"
command = "uptime"

# load ssh config
conf = paramiko.SSHConfig()
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/config')) as config_file:
          conf.parse(config_file)
params = conf.lookup(host)

# connect via ssh
with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(params['hostname'], username=params.get('user'),
                key_filename=params.get('identityfile'), # use ssh keys
                compress=params.get('compression'))

    # run command
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    stdin.close() # no input for the command

    # get output of the command
    with stdout, stderr:
        print("stdout: %r" % (stdout.read(),))
        print('*'*79)
        print("stderr: %r" % (stderr.read(),))
```

Comment: Прошу меня извинить, что не добавил тэг windows, основная проблема именно с этим. Поэтому данное решение не подходит *sad*.

Comment: @St.Gleb: paramiko работает и на Винде. Начнём с простого, работает ли `plink.exe`: `plink -v -ssh -i C:\Users\you\.ssh\private_key.ppk user@host uptime`? Если работает, то добавьте в вопрос соответствующую рабочую команду. Если не работает, то следует задать отдельный вопрос по `plink`.

Comment: @St.Gleb, у меня на винде оба примера работают, я говорю - проблема с `ssh.close()` связана, а не с выполнением команды, команда выполняется нормально, сделайте вывод и увидите